# com.foursquare.android.nativeoauth.FoursquareInternalErrorException: net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED

Tags: android, oauth2

Estoy desarrollando una app en android Studio que se autentica con Foursquare y cuando ejecuto mi app en un celular ASUS Zenfone 4 funciona correctamente, pero luego ejecuto en un celular Huawei Y9 Prime y no funciona. Al hacer debug encuentro que esta instrucción:

```
val codigoRespuesta = FoursquareOAuth.getAuthCodeFromResult(resultCode, data)
```

me genera una excepción que es:

> com.foursquare.android.nativeoauth.FoursquareInternalErrorException:
>   net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED

Alguien me puede ayudar a identificar la causa del error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error `ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED` indica que tu aplicación no permite el uso de urls no cifradas, es decir  `http://` solo puedes usar urls  `https://`.

Desde Android 9 (API level 28) el soporte cleartext esta desactivado por default, por lo que tienes que activarlo para que tu aplicación pueda permitir el uso de urls no cifradas es decir `http://`

Puedes activarlo desde tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<application
    ...
    ...              
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ...
    ...
    >
```

Comment: Gracias Tocayo..... tu respuesta me solucionó el inconveniente. En cuanto a la pregunta que hice donde planteo que Foursquare no me retorna el código de autenticación, lo que hice fue desinstalar la app de Foursquare de mi celular y así funcionó. Gracias por contribuir a mi proceso de formación... espero conseguir un trabajo como desarrollador Android.

Comment: @JorgeHernánGómez Excelente, saludos!